# Implementing Lucene without an Analyzer for the used language of content?

Tags: lucene, solr

Does it make sense?

For my client it's too expensive to develop the Analyzer for Croatian language, I did not find any existing ones...so my question is...do I tell them to drop the idea of Lucene for Croatian content?

Thanks!

Comment: What requirements? Diacritics? Stemming? Synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Muir, Chris Male and others built [a Lucene Morphological Analyzer based on Hunspell](http://lucene-eurocon.org/slides/European-Language-Analysis-with-Hunspell_Chris-Male.pdf). The code [is here](http://code.google.com/p/lucene-hunspell/). Croatian is one of the supported languages in the list.
There may be licensing issues as hunspell is GPL, I think, but it is well worth checking.

Answer (score 2):

[Sematext's Morphological Analyzer](http://sematext.com/products/morpho-analyzer/index.html) claims to support Croatian.